# How to extract methods from export object

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

In my `connector.js` has a object with 2 methods. I just exports the hole object to extract the individual methods in future. but not works. anything wrong with me?

connectors.js

```
const triggers = {
  add: function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {};
  },
  remove: function countReducer(dispatch) {
    return {
      decount: () => {
        const action = { type: "DECREASE" };
        dispatch(action);
      }
    };
  }
};

export default triggers;
```

trying to fetch the methods... but not works.

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import triggers, { add, remove } from "./connectors"; //what is wrong here?

const Decounter = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>I am Decounter!!</h1>
      <button onClick={props.decount}>Decrement</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default connect(
  add,
  remove
)(Decounter);
```

if I use `triggers.add or triggers.remove` - works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you are exporting whole object as default thus you can't import it's params as named.

**#1 approach:** you can do as it is but destructure it at the top of a file:

```
import triggers from "./connectors";

const { add, remove } = triggers;
```

**#2 approach:** use named functions and export them directly:

```
export const add = function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {};
};

export const remove = function countReducer(dispatch) {
  return {
    decount: () => {
      const action = {
        type: "DECREASE"
      };
      dispatch(action);
    }
  }
};
```

And then import:

```
import { add, remove } from './connectors';
```

Hope it will helps.